# Calling two methods on the same id in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I probably haven't got the terminology correct on this (which is why searching for help on this is proving very difficult) so I apologise in advance...

I need to call two methods(?) on the same ID in jQuery.

Here is what I have currently:-

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#pinterest-feed').dcPinterestFeed({
            id: 'lolshop',
            results: 20
            });

        $('#pinterest-feed').simplyScroll({
                speed: 1,
                frameRate: 20,
                orientation: "horizontal",
                direction: "forwards",
                customClass: "pinterest_scroller",
                automode: "loop"
            });
            $("#pinterest_spinner").remove()
});
```

simplyScroll does append itself to the id `pinterest-feed` but the scroll doesn't activate. I presume it is because there is a method (`.dcPinterestFeed`) already being triggered for that id, I don't know?

Should I write the above differently to ensure both methods (`dcPinterestFeed` and `simplyScroll`) work?

Another instance of `simplyScroll` is working perfectly fine on the same page (different ID) and other than id/class names, the code is identical (other than the jQuery) so by process of elimination, it would appear it only doesn't work in this instance is due to the above jQuery.

I know the issue isn't because there are two instances of `simplyScroll` on the same page because I completely removed the second instance and this instance (above) still didn't scroll.

There are no errors in the console on page load but however, if I run the following in the console, the scrolling starts as I'm trying to achieve:-

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#pinterest-feed').simplyScroll({
            speed: 1,
            frameRate: 20,
            orientation: "horizontal",
            direction: "forwards",
            customClass: "pinterest_scroller",
            automode: "loop"
        });
        $("#pinterest_spinner").remove()
});
```

I'm relatively certain that the issue preventing the scrolling is the way the two methods are contained within the top jQuery code included.

Can anyone point out how it should be wrote?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. Maybe those plugins are doing something fishy or are just not compatible. Have you tried removing the call to `.dcPinterestFeed` to check if the other one works then?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. Well `dcPinterestFeed` loads the content within `#pinterest-feed` that needs to scroll but I have just removed the jQuery for `dcPinterestFeed` and manually inserted content into `#pinterest-feed` and can confirm that this does scroll perfectly (as well as the second instance of `simplyScroll`).

Comment: Perhaps the content has not loaded fast enough within `#pinterest-feed` before `simplyScroll` is executed on the id?

Comment: I thought so too. Does that pinterest plugin fire any events you can listen to?

Comment: [I don't think so...](http://pastebin.com/XWVryLhk)?

Comment: Funny thing: You can actually add a `callback` to the function call, but it seems like it gets dropped internally (compare lines 78, 84 and 3). Or am I missing something? Looks like you have to rewrite that plugin.

Comment: Hmm, I'm hopeless with JS :/ looking into it though, got script from [here](http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/jquery-tutorial-create-a-pinterest-feed-jquery-plugin-using-ajax-jquery-isotope/). Thanks

Comment: Okay, I fixed it, it was indeed a timing issue. I just set a timeout on second function. Don't know if there is a more ethical fix and I don't doubt the plugin is wrote poorly (which I wouldn't be able to write any better). Posting answer - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there wasn't anything wrong with the jQuery code but the contents of `#pinterest-feed` was not loading quick enough before `.simplyScroll` was being executed.

Setting a `setTimeout` on `simplyScroll` did the trick and now the contents of `#pinterest-feed` scroll as intended.

```
    setTimeout(function() {

        $('#pinterest-feed').simplyScroll({
                speed: 1,
                frameRate: 20,
                orientation: "horizontal",
                direction: "forwards",
                customClass: "pinterest_scroller",
                automode: "loop"
            });
            $("#pinterest_spinner").remove()

    }, 3000);
```

Phew.